# Presto Build JSON Array with Different Data Types

Tags: sql, json, presto

My goal is to get a JSON array of varchar `name`, varchar `age`, and a LIST of `books_read` (array(varchar)) for EACH `id`

`books_read` has following format: `["book1", "book2"]`

Example Given Table:

| id | name | age | books_read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 21 | ["book1", "book2"] |

Expected Output:

| id | info |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"name":"John", "age":"21", "books_read":["book1", "book2"]}] |

When I use the following query I get an error (`All ARRAY elements must be the same type: row(varchar, varchar)`) because books_read is not of type varchar like name and age.

```
select id, 
array_agg(CAST(MAP_FROM_ENTRIES(ARRAY[
                            ('name', name),
                            ('age', age),
                            ('books_read', books)
                            ]) AS JSON)) AS info
                from tbl
                group by id
```

Is there an alternative method that allows multiple types as input to the array?

I've also tried doing `MAP_CONCAT(MAP_AGG(name), MAP_AGG(age), MULTIMAP_AGG(books_read))` but it also gives me an issue with the `books_read` column: `Unexpected parameters` for the function map_concat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast data to json before placing it into the map:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, name, age, books_read) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'John', 21, array['book1', 'book2'])
) 

-- query
select id,
    cast(
        map(
            array [ 'name', 'age', 'books_read' ],
            array [ cast(name as json), cast(age as json), cast(books_read as json) ]
        ) as json
    ) info
from dataset
```

Output:

| id | info |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"age":21,"books_read":["book1","book2"],"name":"John"} |